How to show unused Javascript variables?
In 2024, how do you get Visual Studio Code 1.95.1 to highlight unused Javascript variables?

By default it makes unused variables in darker grey color, how can I help?

I don't see that happening. I just added an unused variable and it is the default light blue.

I think you should provide more context, screenshots and so, vscode version...

You can use ESlint to either throw out an error for the unused variables or give you warnings.
Check this example
Rule Details
Packages
Updated with steps.

run npm init to set up npm packages if you havent done it.
npm init

install eslint
npm i eslint

create new file eslint.config.js

module.exports = {`
  files: ["**/*.js", "**/*.cjs", "**/*.mjs"],
  rules: {
      "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  }
};




** you can modify your rules here.

Then run eslint on your js file.
npx eslint yourfile.js



When you install that extension, how does ESLINT run? Do you have to do anything to invoke it? And how do you disable it? Thanks!

Added updated answer for javascript files.
Depends on what you are using.
For reactjs, it is installed when you create your react app and can modify its rules from package.json.
